# How to return different Views from switch case

Tags: swiftui

I have this function in my SwiftUI code

```
func getShape(shape:Int, i: Int) -> some View {
    switch self.selectedShape {
    case 0:
        return Rectangle()
               .stroke(Color.pink)
               .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
               .position(CGPoint(x: scrCenterX, y: scrCenterY))
               .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(i) * Double(self.angleStep)))
    case 1:
        return Circle()
               .stroke(Color.pink)
               .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
               .position(CGPoint(x: scrCenterX, y: scrCenterY))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(i) * Double(self.angleStep)))
    case 2:
        return Capsule()
               .stroke(Color.pink)
               .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
               .position(CGPoint(x: scrCenterX, y: scrCenterY))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(i) * Double(self.angleStep)))
    default:
        return Rectangle()
        .stroke(Color.pink)
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .position(CGPoint(x: scrCenterX, y: scrCenterY))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(i) * Double(self.angleStep)))
    }
}
```

and compliler says that "Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types". If I change in all "cases" shape to e.g. Circle then code is compiled without any error. How I cold achieve returning shape based on selectedShape value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`some View` is an Opaque (to the **caller**) return type that is some type that conforms to View. But it has to be a specific type known at compile-time to the callee.

So, at compile-time, you need to decide which concrete type conforming to View it's going to be. It cannot be either `Rectangle` or `Circle`; it always needs to be the same type. So what you're trying to do is not possible (by design) with opaque types.

Instead, you would need to type erase into `AnyView`:

```
func getShape(shape:Int, i: Int) -> AnyView {

   switch self.selectedShape {
   case 0: return AnyView(Rectangle()
                          .stroke(Color.pink)
                          .frame (...)
                          )
   case 1: return AnyView(Circle()
                          .stroke(Color.pink)
                          .frame (...)
                          )
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Preserve the original type:

You should implement a custom view with a custom view builder so you can return different types:

So implement this:

```
struct Shape: View {
    let selected: Int

    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        switch selected {
        case 0: Rectangle()
        case 1: Circle()
        case 2: Capsule()
        default: Rectangle()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have this:

```
func getShape(shape:Int, i: Int) -> some View {
    Shape(selected: shape)
        .stroke(Color.pink)
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .position(CGPoint(x: scrCenterX, y: scrCenterY))
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(i) * Double(self.angleStep)))
}
```

Note that there is no need to write `@ViewBuilder` from Swift 5.3 (Xcode 12)